# Applying a selection group formula to a crosstab

Tags: formula, crosstab, crystal-reports-2013

Crystal reports 13.

I have a report that shows the most recent order for each customer/order id combination. This works perfectly in displaying correctly in Details.

However, when I try to summarise this data in a crosstab, the formula I used isn't applied so I get totals including all records for each customer/order id. I am not sure how I get a crosstab to apply a formula that I have entered in `Report>>>selection formulas>>>Group`.

Not tried anything as not sure where to start.

```
{@Verify Date_Time}=Maximum({@Verify Date_Time},{@Orders_inkpid and inkordid combination})
```

Where

`@verify Date_time` is the most recent order.

`@orders_inkpid` and `inkordid` is the reference I have created to display a unique customer/order combination.

To clarify: this works perfectly in `Details`, I just can't apply it to a crosstab.

I would expect the crosstab to take account of the Group formulas but I guess it calculates before the Group formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the report records using a Crystal Command or a Database View as the data source to achieve the filtering upfront.

Comment: Ok thanks very much for replying. I will learn how to do that and try it out.

Comment: Sorry I am not overly familiar with Commands. I use the tables themselves mainly rather than making a command.

Comment: Do you mean take the existing sql from my report from Database, Show Sql copy it and then paste into a brand new report. That report will now be using a command and then set up my formulas and apply the Group Formulas at that stage?